# is there a match function to bold text in ruby or rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

hi im creating a tags system, and when the user types, i want the results to be bolded where they match the characters the user is typing

where my tags get rendered is here...

```
@tags = Tag.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
render json: @tags.map{ |tag| {:label => "#{tag.name} x #{tag.count}", :value => tag.name} }
```

what the user is typing can be fetched from params[:term]. is there a match function that can bold the appropriate characters as the user types?

thanks

Comment: This is on a web page, in a textarea or rich text input? If so, this is entirely up to JavaScript running in the web browser, and completely unrelated to Ruby or Ruby on Rails running on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller isn't the best place for manipulating with response body. But nevertheless, you can do it this way:

1. Put `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` in your controller class.
2. Use `highlight` helper in your action.

Like here:

```
s = highlight('Ruby on Rails', 'rails', :highlighter => '<strong>\1</strong>')
# => "Ruby on <strong>Rails</strong>"
```